# Running commands from chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I am using chrome console to get data from one site with these 2 commands.

```
window.location.replace(link);

document.forms[2].submit();
```

Is there any way to run theme together in the same line or make a loop ?? Because i want to run in many times

Comment: crate a function and execute it..

Comment: Or just write them one after another: window.location.replace(link); document forms[2].submit();

Comment: Or use an IIFE, or use Shift+Enter to drop onto a new line without executing. This is a Chrome issue, not a programming one.

Comment: @RGraham I don't agree: Chrome developer tools is for debugging, so it's a tool for programmers. So the question is not off-topic, in my opinion

Comment: @Pablo Fair point, vote retracted

Comment: @PeteTNT does not work because document forms[2].submit(); doesn't get the new loaded site. Also tried with a wait function between these two commands but doesn't work. Will try now with snippet but u think its the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Chrome Dev Tools Snippets FTW

Open Dev tools, navigate to the `Sources` tab, open the sidebar on the left, and open the `Snippets` tab. Now right click and create new snippet, put your code inside it, and run it via `Ctrl+Enter`. These snippets stay there untill you delete them, even after chrome restart. They are very powerfull and easy to use.

> [image: Sample Image]

Read more in the official article [Authoring Development Workflow #Snippets](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/authoring-development-workflow#snippets)